# I can't display any linux right anymore after starting to use a new video card on my pc -hd 6570-

Tags: boot, graphics

I'm running windows 8 right now. everything looks and works quite fine and my new video card runs the games nicely. I was able to install ubuntu before I started using my new video card

I decided to install ubuntu but ubuntu, fedora..mint all of them look weird on the screen. I think I can describe what I can see as..dead coloured background and over it there are red dots that make stripe patterns..but there are no dots on texts..

like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/23963038.png/ it happens even if i try booting with safe graphics mode.
notice that there are no dots on "ubuntu" text. I'm able to install ubuntu with a screen like that by choosing "install ubuntu".. but ubuntu won't really work at all after installing

sometimes it shows the error that starts with "panic occured ..." and doesn't even shutdown..i'm not able to write commands like reboot then.

is there any way to fix this?

AMD HD 6570 Video Card,
Asus M5A78L-M LX Motherboard,
Amd Phenom II X4 CPU

note: there are no problems with running linux via virtualbox.

Comment: What video card are you using? We need the make and model. Sounds like a driver issue.

Comment: okay I gave the information about my pc

Answer (score 0):

There was no fglrx to uninstall.

I'm installing `fglrx` ....AND DONE :P Everything is alright no problem at all :D